# 'The argument of type WCHAR* is not compatible with "const char*"'

Tags: c++, memory

```
DWORD ProcMem::Module(LPSTR ModuleName){


HANDLE hModule = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwPID);
MODULEENTRY32 mEntry;
mEntry.dwSize = sizeof(mEntry); 

do
    if (!strcmp(mEntry.szModule, ModuleName))
    {
    CloseHandle(hModule);
    return (DWORD)mEntry.modBaseAddr;
    }
while (Module32Next(hModule, &mEntry));

cout << "\nMODULE: Process Platform Invalid\n";
return 0;
 }
```

the argument of type WCHAR* is not compatible with "const char*"`.
while holding my cursor on mEntry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project is compiled with Unicode enabled, so `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` maps to `CreateToolhelp32SnapshotW()`, `PROCESSENTRY32` maps to `PROCESSENTRY32W`, and `Process32Next()` maps to `Process32NextW()`.  Thus, `ProcEntry.szExeFile` field is a `WCHAR[]` array.

You are passing `szExeFile` to `strcmp()`, which does not support `wchar_t*` strings, only `char*` strings.  You need to either:

1. use `WideCharToMultiByte()` to convert `szExeFile` to a `char[]` array so you can then pass that to `strcmp()`.
2. change your `ProcessName` parameter to `wchar_t*`, or use `MultiByteToWideChar()` to convert `ProcessName` to a `wchar_t[]` array, and pass that to `wcscmp()` or `lstrcmpW()` instead of `strcmp()`.
3. if you want to continue using `TCHAR`-based APIs, change your `ProcessName` parameter to `LPTSTR` and then use `_tcscmp()` or `lstrcmp()` instead of `strcmp()`.

Comment: still got a other problem which i have to fix. but cant be fixed by using lstrcmp().

Comment: @Leon: If it is related to the code in this question, edit this question to include the new code. Otherwise, please post a new question.