# Argument type "WCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Tags: c++

Found this useful code below, here in forum but it raised an error at this line

```cpp
if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, "target.exe") == 0)
```

says

> Argument type "WCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *".

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

void EnableDebugPriv()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    LUID luid;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid);

    tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &tkp, sizeof(tkp), NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(hToken);
}

int main(int, char* [])
{
    EnableDebugPriv();

    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, "target.exe") == 0)
            {
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);

                // Do stuff..

                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not using the `w*` prefixed version of `stricmp`, like [`_wcsicmp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stricmp-wcsicmp-mbsicmp-stricmp-l-wcsicmp-l-mbsicmp-l?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I think the bigger issue is that you are not familiar with what that error means.  Knowing the difference between wide characters, narrow characters, ASCII, Unicode, UTF-8, etc. are huge topics.  You really can't skip over knowing what character encoding and handling is all about.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes am totally out of it because this is my first time to use c++ and it is very urgent. But what i didn't understand, it was a correct answer to this thread or should i say the best answer to what i need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c

Comment: (_tcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, _T("target.exe")) == 0) i miss this thing, it fixed the error :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['The argument of type WCHAR\* is not compatible with "const char\*"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276789/the-argument-of-type-wchar-is-not-compatible-with-const-char)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are compiling your project with its Character Set option set to Unicode, so `Process32First()` and `Process32Next()` map to their Unicode versions, thus `entry.szExeFile` is a `WCHAR[]` array.

But `stricmp()` takes `char` input instead, which is why the code fails to compile.

You need to use the Unicode version of `stricmp` instead, which is `wcsicmp()` or `_wcsicmp()`, eg:

```
if (wcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, L"target.exe") == 0)
```

Or better, use `_tcsicmp()` in `<tchar.h>`, since you are actually using the `TCHAR` version of the `Process32...` functions, eg:

```
if (_tcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, _T("target.exe")) == 0)
```